# Selector to apply jQuery event to two DOM ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have two select menus (#id1 and #id2) that, when validated as containing a user error, should instigate some DOM changes (remove error notice) when either one of them gets interacted with.

Again:

```
var Heat_Check = jQuery('#id1' or '#id2').change(function() { ... });
```

PS. I know there's no return value from that chain.

Comment: You can use `,` for `#id1` or `#id2` if that is what you are looking for. `jQuery('#id1, #id2').change(function() { ... });`

Comment: To follow on from @Vega's comment, this is documented in the jQuery API as a "[multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you wanted to check if `change` is triggered from either of those select. Try below,

```
var Heat_Check = false;

jQuery('#id1, #id2').change(function() { Heat_Check = true; });

function heatCheck () {
   if(Heat_Check) {
      //Do your stuff
      console.log('It is hot');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The comment from @Vega is right, but for completeness you can also do this:

```
 heatChangeHandler = function() {
     // ....
 };

 $('#id1').change(heatChangeHandler);
 $('#id2').change(heatChangeHandler);
```

In general it is better to put multiple selectors in one `$()`, but it's worth knowing that functions can be addressed as variables, and thus referenced many times.